# Could delineating argument of item with curly brackets lead to issues in a large document?

Tags: itemize

Could `item{<text>}` instead of `\item <text>` lead to issues in a large document?

Comment: I honestly don’t see how. If the opening and closing parentheses are very far apart, then maybe the author could lose track. But many editors can match braces just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the document is not really relevant but the constructs are not equivalent so you may get a different output, so that could be classed as an issue.

`\item`  does not take an argument so, despite the phrasing in the question title, the braces in

```
\item{...}
```

do not delineate an argument, they form a TeX Group, limiting the scope of definitions, fonts etc inside.

So the following document produces

[image]

where the extra braces scoped the font change so the first ccc is not bold, but the version without braces the ccc is in the scope of the font change, so is bold.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item{ aaa \bfseries bbb}
\item ccc
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item aaa \bfseries bbb
\item ccc
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Note that `\item` is not related to this at all you would see the same from

```
{ aaa \bfseries bbb} ccc

 aaa \bfseries bbb ccc
```

Comment: Another example would be `\item[foo] bar` vs `\item{[foo] bar}` (Coming from a field in which items containing elements in square brackets are common.)